# Auto-resolve dilemma dialog

Tags: the-sims-4

A streamer let their sims 4 game run while they took a nap, and we, viewers, watched while this household slowly spiralled into chaos with various things around the house breaking. There was however one problem. When a sim is at their work, they sometimes have a 'dilemma' that requires human interaction. A popup appears in the game with a situation at work and the player needs to choose one out of 2 options. This pauses the game, and will not disappear until the player clicks.

This made me wonder. Is there a configuration setting to either disable this popup or to auto-resolve the popup by choosing one of the options automatically?

Comment: I know that in Sims 3, you can go into the game options and check the "[Suppress opportunities](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110610204228/sims/images/7/70/Ts3_opt_go.jpg)" which I *believe* causes the options to stop coming up. If you press F5, and go into the Game Options section in TS4, I assume the same or similar option is there (I myself do not actually own the game). As for your second question, there is probably a way to code something to auto-answer the question for you, but I do not think there is a setting you can change that will answer them.

Comment: I just looked in the Options menu, I don't see any option like that in Sims 4.